# Unable to pip install virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I was trying to install a virtual environment by the command:
`pip install virtualenv`
and I get:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\program files\python37\python.exe"  "C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe" install virtualenv': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I would like to hear if someone could help me.

Comment: Does your `pip.exe` file exist?

Comment: Yes, it exists.

Comment: N.B. you can usually just use the [builtin `venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) instead of `virtualenv`: `python -m venv ./venv`.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```py
python -m pip install virtualenv
```

Comment: it works fine until I type "virtualenv venv":

Comment: `python -m virtualenv venv`

Comment: I can't believe it works!

Comment: Why is that? Do I always need to write python -m instead of pip?